# Convert hex value to a decimal value in VB6

Tags: vb6

How can I convert a hex value to a decimal value in VB6?

I'm trying just to see if this works:

```
Dim hexVal as string
hexVal = "#7B19AB"
clng("&H" & hexVal)
```

However, I'm getting "**Type MisMatch**" error.

Comment: Ahh, you mean "convert a hex String to a binary Long."  There is no "decimal" involved at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Get rid of the # sign

```
Dim hexVal as string
hexVal = "7B19AB"
clng("&H" & hexVal)
```

Comment: For large numbers you might need to use the technique below else it gives you negative numbers

https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2042&lngWId=1

https://pastebin.com/UjzD4N8m

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the number sign (#) in the hexVal string.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```
Dim hexVal as String
hexVal = "#7B19AB"
Dim intVal as Integer
intVal = Val("&H" & Replace(hexVal, "#", ""))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try It:

```
value=CDbl("&H" & HexValue)
```

or

```
value=CInt("&H" & HexValue) 'but range +- 32,768
```

Comment: Thank you for posting that answer but it is a duplicate of others already posted and accepted. If you want to improve an existing anser, please edit it and it will be reviewed by others in the community.

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way:

```
Print Hex(Asc(Text1.Text))
```

Answer (score 1):

Be very carful.

```
Dim hexVal as string
hexVal = "FFFF"
clng("&H" & hexVal)
```

will return a value of -1 because it thinks your HEX value is signed. 
See what happens with F00A, again it thinks its signed.

Replace the Clng with ABS.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim uzunluk as Integer

On Error Resume Next
uzunluk = Len(Text1.Text)
For i = 0 To uzunluk
     Text1.SelStart = i
     Text1.SelLength = 1
     Print Hex(Asc(Text1.SelText))
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim hexVal As String
Dim str As String
Dim uzunluk As Integer

On Error Resume Next

hexVal = "#7B19AB" 

str = Replace(hexVal, "#", "")
Text1.Text = str

uzunluk = Len(Text1.Text) 

For i = 0 To uzunluk 
    Text1.SelStart = i 
    Text1.SelLength = 1 
    Print Hex(Asc(Text1.SelText))
Next i
```