# VB6 Hashing SHA1 output not matched

Tags: hash, vb6, sha1

need help for my problem here. i do searching and googling for this problem but still don't found the solution why my output didnt matched with the expected output.

data to hash : 
0800210142216688003333311100000554478000000

expected output : 
DAAC526D4806C88CEDB8B7C6EA42A7442DE6E7DC

my output : 
805C790E6BF39E3482067C44909EE126F9CBB878

and i am using this function to generate the hash

```
Public Function HashString(ByVal Str As String, Optional ByVal Algorithm As HashAlgorithm = SHA1) As String
On Error Resume Next
Dim hCtx As Long
Dim hHash As Long
Dim lRes As Long
Dim lLen As Long
Dim lIdx As Long
Dim AbData() As Byte
lRes = CryptAcquireContext(hCtx, vbNullString, vbNullString, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)
If lRes <> 0 Then
    lRes = CryptCreateHash(hCtx, Algorithm, 0, 0, hHash)
    If lRes <> 0 Then
        lRes = CryptHashData(hHash, ByVal Str, Len(Str), 0)
        If lRes <> 0 Then
            lRes = CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHSIZE, lLen, 4, 0)
            If lRes <> 0 Then
                ReDim AbData(0 To lLen - 1)
                lRes = CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, AbData(0), lLen, 0)
                If lRes <> 0 Then
                    For lIdx = 0 To UBound(AbData)
                        HashString = HashString & Right$("0" & Hex$(AbData(lIdx)), 2)
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        End If
        CryptDestroyHash hHash
    End If

End If
CryptReleaseContext hCtx, 0
If lRes = 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.LastDllError
End If
End Function
```

and this is command to call the function

```
Dim received As String
Dim HASH As String

HASH = "0800210142216688003333311100000554478000000"

received = HashString(HASH)

Debug.Print ("HASH VALUE : " & received)
```

thanks

**UPDATE:**

finally i managed to get the expected output. i change the function to generate the sha1 using the sha1 function in this website :
http://vb.wikia.com/wiki/SHA-1.bas

and i do use this function to convert my hexstring to byte array

```
Public Function HexStringToByteArray(ByRef HexString As String) As Byte()
    Dim bytOut() As Byte, bytHigh As Byte, bytLow As Byte, lngA As Long
    If LenB(HexString) Then
        ' preserve memory for output buffer
        ReDim bytOut(Len(HexString) \ 2 - 1)
        ' jump by every two characters (in this case we happen to use byte positions for greater speed)
        For lngA = 1 To LenB(HexString) Step 4
            ' get the character value and decrease by 48
            bytHigh = AscW(MidB$(HexString, lngA, 2)) - 48
            bytLow = AscW(MidB$(HexString, lngA + 2, 2)) - 48
            ' move old A - F values down even more
            If bytHigh > 9 Then bytHigh = bytHigh - 7
            If bytLow > 9 Then bytLow = bytLow - 7
            ' I guess the C equivalent of this could be like: *bytOut[++i] = (bytHigh << 8) || bytLow
            bytOut(lngA \ 4) = (bytHigh * &H10) Or bytLow
        Next lngA
        ' return the output
        HexStringToByteArray = bytOut
    End If
End Function
```

and i using this command to get the expected output

```
Dim received As String
Dim HASH As String
Dim intVal As Integer
Dim temp() As Byte

HASH = "08002101422166880033333111000005544780000000"

temp = HexStringToByteArray(HASH)

received = Replace(HexDefaultSHA1(temp), " ", "")

Debug.Print ("HASH VALUE : " & received)
```

and finally i got the same output as expected. Yeah!!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `805c...` is the SHA1 hash of the *characters* in your input string, i.e. `'0', '8', '0', '0', ...`
- `daac...` is the SHA1 hash of the characters in your input string after conversion of each pair of hexadecimal digits to a *byte*, i.e. `0x08, 0x00, ...`

[Convert the input string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798759/how-convert-hex-string-into-byte-array-in-vb6) to an array of bytes prior to hashing.

Comment: This would be correct, except... his input value isn't hex at all.  It has an odd number of digits.  Though if I tack on another `0` at the end I get the result he seems to expect as long as I do the conversion you suggest and feed these *bytes* into the hash instead of the *Unicode text* he is using.

Comment: if i need to convert my input into the array of bytes, it means i cant use the same function right?..cause my current function required the input as string..should i modify the current function to read input as a byte array and how to modify it?

Comment: Why not just decode the String of hex into bytes within your function? `CryptStringToBinary()` can be used to do that, which is the main reason it exists.

Comment: Finally, i manage to get the expected output. thanks to all of your for the guide to my problem ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Your output is correct. This is SHA1 using python:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> s = hashlib.sha1('0800210142216688003333311100000554478000000')
>>> s.hexdigest()
'805c790e6bf39e3482067c44909ee126f9cbb878'
```

Where did you get the other SHA1 computation from?

Comment: i got the output using the Bp-tools from eftlab and my required is to get the same output as expected.

Comment: there is one online tool that can generate same like my expected output http://cnp-wireless.com/Tools/sha1-luhn.php